# Plupload how to continue to upload after UploadComplete

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm using plupload 1.5.7, jQuery Queue Widget, after the upload complete the **Add files** and **Start Upload** buttons disappear, replaced by a label **Upload 1/1 files**.

Now I can't add others files, I need to refresh the page and upload other files.
I've tried also the **uploader.splice()** and **uploader.refresh()** methods without success.

Is it possible after an upload - *of one or more files* - to continue to upload?

My actual configuration is:

```js
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    url: '/upload.php',
    max_file_size: '10mb',
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    unique_names: true,

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters: [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,png"}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',

    init: {

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {},
        UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
            up.splice();
            up.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use to proceed somewhat like this (sorry, can't test it right now), embedding my initialization code in a function which I can call whenever I want.

```
va initUploader = function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        url: '/upload.php',
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [{
            title: "Image files",
            extensions: "jpg,png"
        }],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',

        init: {

            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {},
            UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                // destroy the uploader and init a new one
                up.destroy();
                initUploader();
            }
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){initUploader();});
```

Answer (score 4):

The Buttons you're looking for are still available but not displayed.
So instead of reinitializing the Uploader, you can just change the display CSS option via JS, like that:

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function() {
  $(".plupload_buttons").css("display", "inline");
  $(".plupload_upload_status").css("display", "inline");
})
```

Or if you are attaching your Events in the init function:

```
UploadComplete: function() {
  $(".plupload_buttons").css("display", "inline");
  $(".plupload_upload_status").css("display", "inline");
}
```

Note that im using jQuery in this example, but it would also work with plain JS.