# Disable PLUpload Image uploader until checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, plupload

I am making one form in which Required shield Logo upload for system if and only if user checked the checked box **Shield description Required**. I have made enable text area on checked the checkbox. But if i made PlUpload button disable then even it allow to upload the image.

I have also tried to initialize PLUpload on `checked on` event but PlUpload is only initialize on `document.ready` as i know.

[image]

i.e If User required to checked on the required description then i make Textarea enable(default is disabled) and able to upload logo image by PLUpload.

Comment: you can init on a click event, provided you correctly wrapped uploader initialization . see for example  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16690861/1236044